# Move Excel Selection to first column (offset?)

Tags: excel, vba

How do I move my current selection to the first column of the sheet retaining the same rows.
Example - Current selection - D3,D4,D6 selection moved to A3,A4,A6 (Columns of the current selection will change and not the same as D)

```
Selection.Offset(x, x).Select
```

Can I use the selection offset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it with `Offset` you can do it like that:

```
Sub test()

Dim x As Long
x = Selection.Column
Selection.Offset(0, -x + 1).Select

End Sub
```

x is the column of your current selection, take this amount of column out to go to the first column.

Answer (score 0):

Could you perhaps do something like this? A cut and insert in macro form. Replace the strings with your selection.

```
Columns("B").Cut
Columns("F").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```

Comment: Alternatively, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688864/excel-macro-to-move-column) for a similar question that was answered.

Comment: I was looking for a way to select without changing data, @Pierre44's solution works.