# Is there a neat and tidy way to reorder columns in an excel table with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

EDIT: Ended up just loading the whole thing into an array and printing the columns in the order i want

Currently I use the following code to reorder columns in an excel table in VBA. Crucially i must maintain the formatting of the table. The way it works currently is the desired order is loaded into an array and than searching through the table for that header. when its found cut and insert the columns to the far right of the table. Eventually the columns will be an order. However the code runs very slow and it feels like a really dirty way to do it. I was wondering if there is a cleaner way. Ideally i would like to eliminate the use of the clipboard however that is not important.

The 3 goals for this were to maintain the table formatting, handle missing columns, and handle extra columns. Extra columns naturally end up on the right.

Any help is appreciated

```
Private Sub ColumnArranger
    Dim CorrectOrder As Variant
    Dim i As Variant
    Dim tblComp As ListObject

    Set tblComp = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("BOM_Component_DONE") 'assigns table on completed sheet to variable
    CorrectOrder = Array("No.", "Description", "HTS", "Unit Cost", "TOTAL QTY", "TOTAL COST", " Currency", "Item - Vendor No.") 'this should be the desired order
    
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each i In CorrectOrder
        Columns(tblComp.ListColumns(i).Range.Column).Cut
        Columns(tblComp.ListColumns.Count + 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Next i
    On Error GoTo 0
    

End Sub
```

Comment: Turning `Application.Calculation` to manual before the entire moving process and turing it to automatic after will prevent re-calculation after each move. Also turning off `Application.ScreenUpdating` will gain some speed.

Comment: If you are looking for some sort of `Ordinal` property to adjust for each column, there isn't one.

Comment: What kind of formatting is applied to the columns? Maybe you can store the formatting in an array or collection or whatever makes sense. Then create a new table with the correct column order and number of rows, then write the values per column via `loTarget.listcolumns("No").databodyrange = loSource.listcolumns("No").databodyrange` - and then apply the formatting stored for "No"

Comment: Application screen updating false does help a little bit. I was thinking maybe load the table into an array, write out the data in the correct order and than convert it from a range to a table, than apply formatting. My concern with this was in my experience going from range to table is very slow. Ike are you able to expand a little on what your talking about? The formatting must be as a table because I am creating structured references later in the module. Also some rows are highlighted. Your solution sounds interesting im just very new to VBA so I don’t fully understand. Thanks

Comment: Formatting as a table is no problem. Highlighted rows sounds more complicated. That's why I asked, what kind of formatting has to be kept? Can you describe this a bit more detailed. (you have to use an @ together with the then the user gets informed about your direct question)

Comment: You wrote that you _"Ended up just loading the whole thing into an array and printing the columns in the order i want"_. Please explain here how you did this.

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t a clean solution that I can think of.

If it were me, I'd use `record macro`, identify the formatting code, and update the data table's formatting each time it was used. That way, there isn’t as much restriction on moving the columns around.

There are a few nice tricks here for making column changes undynamically:
[Excel macro to move column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688864/excel-macro-to-move-column)
Dynamically, you could use `.Find` or an `array()` because the header location may change when the `pivot table` is recalculated.

I attempted an `array` below. This code will work to move the columns, but it will not respect the table's `format` and `formula`.

It works by requiring your `CorrectOrder array` which then confines the `loop` to where first in `array()` order is equivalent to `column(1)`, second in array order is column(2), and third is (3).

Perhaps this will get you started.

```
Sub findvalues()
    
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With


    Dim r As Variant
    Dim nRc As Range
    Dim LCol As Long
    

    r = Array("No.", "Description", "HTS", "Unit Cost", "TOTAL QTY", "TOTAL COST", " Currency", "Item - Vendor No.")
    Set nRc = Sheets(3).ListObjects(1).HeaderRowRange
     
  
    LCol = Sheets(3).Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Sheets(3).Cells(1, 1), SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column + 2
    
    For Each it In r
        For Each rng In nRc
            If rng.Value = it Then '
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
               On Error Resume Next
                Sheets(3).ListObjects(1).ListColumns(rng.Column).Range.Cut Sheets(3).Columns(LCol)
                On Error GoTo 0
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                LCol = Sheets(3).Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Sheets(3).Cells(1, 1), SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column + 1
            End If
        Next rng
    Next it
   
   Sheets(3).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(, Sheets(3).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count + 1).EntireColumn.Delete shift:=xlToLeft
 
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
```

Comment: This looks interesting thanks for the work you put into it. I will try this out later today.

Answer (score 0):

With one minor tweak, Brett's solution appears to preserve the formatting and does not break formulas. The tweak is to do the cut and paste in 2 steps, e.g.,

```
 ws.Columns(rng.Column).Select
 Selection.Cut
 ws.Columns(LCol).Select
 Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```

where ws ~ Sheets(3). in Brett's code.

Thanks to OP for the question and Brett for his answer.

I use this on Excel 365 to reorder 140+ columns, about 1/3 with formulas, on worksheets with approximately 1-4k rows of data.

The subroutine is below, note that I pass the active worksheet and array with the column order, ColumnOrder:

```
Sub Reorder_Columns(ByRef ws As Worksheet, ByRef ColumnOrder As Variant)

With Application
   .ScreenUpdating = False
   .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With 

Dim ndx, counter As Integer
Dim r, it As Variant
Dim rng, nRc, Found As Range
Dim LCol  As Long

r = ColumnOrder
Set nRc = ws.ListObjects(1).HeaderRowRange
LCol = ws.Cells.Find(what:="*", After:=ws.Cells(1, 1), SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column + 2
 For Each it In r
        For Each rng In nRc
            If rng.Value = it Then '
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
               On Error Resume Next
                ws.Columns(rng.Column).Select
                Selection.Cut
                ws.Columns(LCol).Select
                Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
                On Error GoTo 0
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
               LCol = ws.Cells.Find(what:="*", After:=ws.Cells(1, 1), SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column + 1
            End If
        Next rng
    Next it
            
End Sub

 With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
         .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 End With

End Sub
```